# "More close" VS "closer"

Tags: adjectives, comparative

I want to express that both of us are not quite right but I am closer. Should I put:

> 1. I'm more close to right than you.
> 2. I'm closer to right than you.

So, which way is correct to express this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the context is that the speaker is debating with someone about whose opinion is correct, the phrase "I'm closer to right than you" sounds strange. This is mainly because "closer to right" is not a common idiom for "being correct." Instead, try

> My story is truer than yours.

or

> My facts are more correct than yours.

If you intend to say that someone's position is more to the east than someone else, then you could say:

> I'm closer to **the** right than you.

That may make sense in context, but you'd almost certainly want to qualify that with the object of which the speaker is to the right. Ex.

> I'm closer to the right of the stage than you.

Note that the former also has the slight political connotation (at least in the US) that the speaker is more conservative. Ex. "I'm closer to the right than you" could be replaced with "I'm more conservative than you."

Answer (score 3):

The comparative of the adjective "close" is **closer**. See, for instance, [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/close). You can say

> I am closer to right than you.